# How to fetch traffic stats for a domain by date from gmailpostmastertools?

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-postmaster

I'm trying to fetch traffic stats by date for a domain through gmailpostmastertools over OAuth2,
I'm able to retrieve postmaster.domains.list and traffic stats for a domain without any date parameters,
when any of the endDate or startDate parameters included in the request, it throws the following,

```
Error: Request contains an invalid argument.
at Gaxios._request (C:\projects\postmaster-api\node_modules\gaxios\src\gaxios.ts:158:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at OAuth2Client.requestAsync (C:\projects\postmaster-api\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:345:18)
```

Here's the condensed bit that tries to fetch the data,

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis';

oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  'client_placeholder',
  'secret_placeholder', 
  '/oauth2callback'
);

postmaster = google.gmailpostmastertools({
  version: 'v1',
  auth: oauth2Client
});

await this.postmaster.domains.trafficStats.list({ 
  'startDate.day'   : 1,
  'startDate.month' : 7,
  'startDate.year'  : 2021,
  parent : `domains/${domain_name}`
});
```

It works fine to fetch the data directly with access_token.

```js
let access_token = 'my_access_token';
let domain_name = 'mydomain.com';
let date = '20210701';
await fetch(`https://gmailpostmastertools.googleapis.com/v1/domains/${domain_name}/trafficStats/${date}?access_token=${access_token}`, {
    method: 'GET'
});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both startDate and endDate in the request.

From https://developers.google.com/gmail/postmaster/reference/rest/v1/domains.trafficStats/list

> startDate: The earliest day of the metrics to retrieve inclusive. startDate and
> endDate must both be specified or both left unspecified. If only one
> is specified, or endDate is earlier in time than startDate, then
> INVALID_ARGUMENT is returned.

Comment: it's not working. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2702